# how Can I display a document from a link in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to programming and I am not able to display a link in my app in flutter

I want to display a document as a privacy policy for my app fetching it from google drive so, that I can upload to play store

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package for displaying document from google drive,
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter
after importing this package, add the code.Example:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Privacy Policy'),
  ),
  body: WebView(
    initialUrl: 'your google drive link here',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  ),
);
```